# Find initial system from solution of a RREF matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was looking at the solution's of my exam.
I used a different technique: I first found the RREF of the matrix giving the solution. Then I worked backward to find the initial system.
Can anyone explain what my prof is doing? I have no idea what he's trying to do.
[image]

Comment: "The system has an infinite number of solutions." not sure what you mean by that. This system has one unique solution.

Comment: Ok. I don't understand what you mean by subbing 3x=-x-2y into the second row.

Answer (score 0):

The second row represents the equation: $x+3y+4z=??$. Plugging in the given solution, $x=-1,y=2, \text{ and } z=-1$, then the missing value must be
$$
(-1)+3(2)+4(-1)=1.
$$

The final row could be anything you wanted it to be, as long as it is consistent with the given solution. The easiest could have been $0x+0y+z=-1$. But other solutions could have looked like $x+2y+3z=0$ since $-1+2(2)+3(-1)=0$ or $256x-14y-23z=-261$ because $256(-1)-14(2)-23(-1)=-261$.

Does this help understand your prof's comment? He meant there were infinitely many different systems of equations that give rise to the given unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't know what your professor is doing. The question you posted is either not complete, or straight weird. Geometrically, if the first two row represent a system of linear equations, then they cannot have "a unique solution." It would be two planes intersecting.